# Provisioning Profile With No Physical Devices

Tags: swift, xcode, certificate, provisioning-profile

I have seen this issue a lot on this forum and apple's developer forum. I have followed tutorials and have been at this for over 6 hours.

All I want is to add the app so I can testflight it with friends and family. I do not have an iphone. I have a Macbook Pro and a paid for Developer enrollment.

When I select Generic IOS Device and Archive I get this error:

```
Failed to create provisioning profile. There are no devices registered in your account on the developer website. Plug in and select a device to have Xcode register it.
```

```
No profiles for '--------------' were found
Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching '--------------'.
```

[image: Errors]

What I tried:

- I have the bundle ID in the Developer Certificate Page
- I have made the app in App Store Connect
- I have gone through the certificate steps and made these certificates in xcode
- I have these certificates in keychain:
- I have tried restarting xcode, cleaning the build, changing build settings.

I still get the two error messages when trying to archive from generic device.

What am I doing wrong? What else should I do?

Comment: Have you donwloaded the provisioning-profiles (dev and dist) and opened or even created these?

Comment: You can create a provisioning profile for Distribution - App Store here https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/profiles/add.

Answer (score 7):

If you use automatic code signing, it is a requirement that you need to have at least one registered device (registered when you run the debug version of the app on it the first time).

In order to do what you are trying to do, you will need to use manual code signing.  On Apple's Developer site, manually create the provisioning profiles.  If you want to send the, the .ipa, you can create a development provisioning profile, and manually register their devices with the device IDs for their device.  But if they are not technically minded, that could be difficult.  It sounds like you've made the decision to use TestFlight (probably the right call), especially since you have a paid developer account.  For that, create a distribution provisioning profile and use that to deploy your app and distribute it via TestFlight.

Comment: Knowing that "You *must* have registered Apple hardware in order to use automatic code signing in xcode" is essential knowledge. Thanks.  I wonder why is it that the fact is not made more obvious?

Comment: I think the expectation is that iOS developers would have at least one physical device for testing.  The simulator is good, but there is still a difference between running your code on a simulator with a faster, powerful CPU and running it on the ARM chip in a mobile device.

Comment: That's a bad assumption... I just bought a Mac only so that I can submit apps to App Store! Not because I want one, but just because it is a requirement... Now, I have to buy an iPhone that I don't want, as well??

Comment: It’s not a bad assumption.  Your use case is a very small minority. And code signing is specifically the process by which you build and sign an executable to run on a physical device.  So automating that to run on your physical devices really only makes sense if you have physical devices.   If you don’t have your own devices, doing one time setup for manual code signing is not an unreasonable expectation.

Answer (score 0):

Extracted from a previous version of the question:

> I had to create a provisioning profile for Distribution - App Store. And then in Xcode turn off Automatically manage signing, and select the provisioning profile manually for Signing (Debug), and Signing (Release).
>
> Now I do not need a physical device to archive, unlike what the linked duplicate states.