# Flutter iOS - Build a release version without a real device?

Tags: ios, flutter, release

As an Android dev, I've been baffled by the idea of building against targets.

I don't have an iOS device and have been debugging against the iOS simulator.

However, I've gotten to a point where I want to disperse a release .ipa to our internal team. Can this be achieved?

When I run `flutter build ios`, I see the following:

```
Xcode's output:
↳
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
    error: Failed to create provisioning profile. There are no devices
    registered in your account on the developer website. Plug in and select a
    device to have Xcode register it. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    error: No profiles for 'xxx.xxx.xxx' were found: Xcode couldn't
    find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching
    'xxx.xxx.xxx'. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
```

Comment: You need to set up a provisioning profile before building it for the real devices. This could be done only if you have an `apple developer account`.
Details can be found here. https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#deploy-to-ios-devices

Comment: It seems I need to register one for Ad Hoc distribution, which requires me to enter the device UUIDs. Does that sound right?

Comment: You don't have to do anything manually, though if you just want to distribute it, you can also put the app in test flight. https://developer.apple.com/testflight/

Comment: I don't see how I don't have to do anything manually.

Comment: Do you have registered developer account?

Comment: I have a same issue. @DipanshKhandelwal In order to use testflight, i have to build an app as release. but as you know, i can't build it because of mentioned error (provisioning profile) so, i think i can't put the app in test flight because i can't build app.  i attached my question below. thank you
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61169373/flutter-ios-should-i-have-to-get-a-real-ios-device-to-upload-appstore

Answer (score 5):

I did google more, and i found it

[Provisioning Profile With No Physical Devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58839128/provisioning-profile-with-no-physical-devices)

> SOLVED:
>
> In case anyone else is having trouble. I had to create a provisioning
>   profile for Distribution - App Store. And then in Xcode turn off
>   Automatically manage signing, and select the provisioning profile
>   manually for Signing(Debug), and Signing (Release).
>
> Now I do not need a physical device to archive, unlike what the linked
>   duplicate states.