# Flutter IOS - Should i have to get a REAL IOS device to upload appstore?

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, testflight, provisioning-profile

i spent 7 days to try to resolve Flutter IOS build issue. please help me

i found similar question with my problem. but there is no answer yet

related issue : [Flutter iOS - Build a release version without a real device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61150078/flutter-ios-build-a-release-version-without-)

before to start,

1. I DON'T HAVE REAL IPHONE, i'm using ios simulator
2. I paid apple developer account
3. i already registered apple developer certificate. i can run my flutter app on ios simulator

[image]

i want to upload my ios app via testflight.
so, i try to build it using

```
flutter build ios
```

and also tried to "archive" from XCode ("Generic IOS Device" is it.) if i chose IOS simulator(like IPHONE 11), "archive" tab never activated)

and then, i got an error that

> Failed to create provisioning profile there are no device registered
>   in your account on the developer website. plug in and select a device
>   to have Xcode register it
>
> No profiles for "com.xxx.xxx" were found Xcode couldn't find any IOS
>   App development provisioning profiles matching "com.xxx.xxx"

I tried to make provisioning profile. but i had to input IOS device UDID. but i DO NOT have IOS device.

is there any way to resolve this error? i really don't know why this happen. 
i just want to use testflight and app store. please please help me..

I've done somethings to fix this issue.

1. Change appname(com.xxx.xxx) as unique one (like com.myownappnamedonotuseit.uniquenameonlyforme)
2. Register provisioning profile ( failed because of UDID, i don't have iphone also UDID)
3. a lot of stuff on internet (remove cache, re login apple account, regenerate certificate)

above things, never works.. please help me

====== reply to @Dipansh Khandelwal

actually, i tried it, but i can't register ios simulator as device
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you sure that you want to upload an app for review that you have never even tried out on a real device? That's preposterous.

Comment: @gnasher729 Thank you  for your reply!  Yes. i checked all function using ios simulator. and i paid  apple developer program.  i don't understand why apple wants to get my own apple device ID when i needs to build ios app as release version

Answer (score 0):

It's fine if you don't have a real phone.
You can also register your ios simulator to the apple developer website and create a provisioning profile.

Comment: thanks for your reply! i've just edited question. i also tried to register ios simulator, but i can't